# Nginx rewrite rule (with try_files?) filename.php?text=$args (to) foldername/?text=$args

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite rule in nginx for the case, when I send parameters with this request **example.com/index.php?text=s1&sort=s2**, but I want nginx to process it as **example.com/process/?text=s1&sort=s2** ?

"s1" and "s2" is something that you type in search form.

I've already tried this:

```
rewrite ^/index.php?text=(.*)$ /process/?text=$1 last;
```

And this:

```
location ~* /index.php?text=(.*)$ {
try_files $uri /search/?text=$1;
#try_files $uri /search/?text=$is_args$args;
}
```

And this..

```
location =index.php?text=$1&sort=$2 {
rewrite index.php?text=$1&sort=$2 /process/text=$1&sort=$2;
}
```

But it somehow doesn't work.

This is main part of my config:

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
include /etc/nginx/php_params;
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

I'm so confused.. :/

Comment: Please do not use the `.htaccess` tag here - it is not applicable to nginx. I have removed the tag.

Comment: Is `/index.php` used for anything else? Or can I rewrite any URI that starts with `/index.php`?

Comment: Yeah, it is already used to short other url paths. For example, I can use "site.com/register" to go here -> site.com/index,php/?register or site.com/login -> site.com/index.php?/login. It's, actually, for Codeigniter Framework.

Comment: Sorry, I misspeled one word in original request. Not example.com/index.php?q=s1&sort=s2 , but example.com/index.php?text=s1&sort=s2 - fixed now. Checking your answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything after the `?` is part of the query string and individual values can be accessed with variable names beginning with the `arg_` prefix.

A simple rewrite of all `/index.php` could be defined using:

```
location = /index.php {
    rewrite ^ /process/?text=$arg_q&sort=$arg_sort? last;
}
```

The final `?` prevents `rewrite` from appending the old query string on to the end of the new URI.

If you wish to single out only those URIs that contain an `$arg_q` parameter, you will need to use an [evil if](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) inside the PHP location block. Like this:

```
location ~* \.php$ {    
    if ($arg_q) {
        rewrite ^/index.php$ /process/?text=$arg_q&sort=$arg_sort? last;
    }
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

1) In your case, the URI is mostly handled by `/index.php`, but the value of `$request_uri` (the original value of the request) is used to route it within `/index.php`. The value of `$request_uri` is difficult to modify without performing an external redirect.

2) When `/index.php` is presented as the original request, you would like it to be routed to `/search/`. The current value of `$request_uri` begins with `/index.php` which is unhelpful.

The solution is to identify unhelpful values of `$request_uri` and perform an external redirect to modify the value of `$request_uri`. Something like this:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^/index.php) {
    return 302 /search/?$args;
}
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
location ~* \.php$ {
    ...
}
```

If the query string is identical, just use `$args` (or `$query_string`) to append it. Otherwise break it into individual arguments as in my original answer.

Comment: I used example from your answer in PHP location block:
if ($arg_text) { rewrite ^/index.php$ /search/?text=$arg_text&sort=$arg_sort? last; }

But unfortunately there is an error (500):
[error] 6163#0: *1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/search/", client: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: _, request: "GET /index.php?text=test&sort=test2 HTTP/1.1"

Comment: I understand the problem. It will depend on what you have in your php_params file but initially, you might try changing the `last` to (1) `redirect` or (2) `break`.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I've got 2 other errors in Browser: with redirect (..redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete..) and with break (No input file specified.).
Maybe it's worth to try something like this:     if ($args ~ text){ return 419}     and make block for processing requests with arg_text like this     error_page 419 = @arg_text; location @arg_text { ... php-fpm params here to rewrite url path..}     I believe that should work, but don't know how to make it..

Comment: The problem looks so simple - just replace "/index.php/" with "/process/" if there is "text" argument - but still can't figure it out :)
Though, it would be easy to make it work with this:
if ($args ~ text) { rewrite /index.php/ /process/; }
:D

Comment: @Oria I have appended some detail to my original answer based on some tests I have run.

Comment: Actually, it works! With $query_string too.
But do you think it's safe and reliable way? People usually try to keep away from "if" blocks. How does it actually work? I'm kind of newbie in nginx rules, but for me it looks like that it checks if the request uri begins with /index.php, and if yes, then it replaces it with other path. What if there are other functions that use /index.php with different $args? Can I somehow check $args? In php language it will be looked like this: if ($request_uri ~ ^/index.php && $args ~ text && $args ~ sort){return 302 /search/?$args;} But not in Nginx))

Comment: Allright, I've found solution for additionally checking $args via seting variables aka multiple if statements nginx replacent =)
Just hope it will work fine. Thanks for help!

Comment: Unfortunately `if` is fairly limited and has side-effects (see [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) and [this](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)). My solution performs an *external redirect* which is perfectly safe with `if`. I try to use `try_files` or `map` before resorting to `if`. But sometimes you need to use `if`. One might ask why is the client sending `index.php` in the first place, which the app requires `nginx` to fiddle with to make things work.

Comment: Also, `$query_string` is equivalent to `$args` see http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html

Answer (score 1):

Not wishing to edit an accepted answer - I would like to offer an alternative solution that I have tested:

```
root ...;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @index;
}

location @index {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri;
    fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
    if ($arg_text) {
        rewrite ^/index.php$ /search/ last;
    }

    try_files $uri =404;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
}
```

This version avoids the immutable `$request_uri` by using `$uri` within a named location. Also the earlier redirect loop is avoided by using the named location for `index.php`.

Comment: Thanks for another answer!
Written fine, but it doesn't work. As I said earlier, I've got other args (index.php/?$args), they work if it's set like this: location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; }
With this new config neither they,nor /search/ with args work.